# Не передаются значения из метода в массив

Tags: java, массивы

```
public class Main {
    final static double a = 1.5;
    final static double deltaX = 0.005;
    static double y = 0;
    static int steps = 0;
    private static double arrayX[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tabul();
        FindStepsQuantity();
        createArrayOfXValues(arrayX);
    }

    public static void Tabul() {
        for (double x = 0.8; x <= 2.0; x = x + deltaX) {
            if (x < 1.7) {
                y = Math.PI * x * x - 7 / x * x;
            }
            else if (x == 1.7) {
                y = a * x * x * x + 7 * Math.sqrt(x) + Math.log10(x + 7 * Math.sqrt(x));
            }
            else {
                y = Math.log10(x + 7 * Math.sqrt(x));
            }
        }
    }

    public static int FindStepsQuantity() {
        for (double i = 0.8; i <= 2.0; i = i + deltaX) {
            steps++;
        }
        System.out.println(steps);
        return steps;
    }

    public static void createArrayOfXValues(double[] array) {
        array = new double[steps];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            y = array[i];
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
```

Не могу понять почему метод `createArrayOfXValues` не заполняет массив значениями `y`, которые были получены в методе `Tabul`. Если `y` статическая переменная, то она ведь должна менять значение после вызова метода `Tabul`.

Что я упускаю?

Comment: Не могу понять почему метод createArrayOfXValues не заполняет массив значениями y которые были получены в методе Tabul(), если y статическая переменная, то она ведь должна менять значение после вызова метода Tabul(), что я упускаю, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Вопрос неясен. Можете указать в вопросе: 1) что происходит при выполнении кода; 2) что именно Вас удивляет 3) что должно происходить. Если вопрос относится к выводу программы, то напишите реальный и ожидаемый вывод. Почитайте [каким должен быть пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе `Tabul` (в Java, кстати, принято называть методы с маленькой буквы) в поле `y` по очереди присваиваются все значения, в результате чего в `y` хранится только последнее значение.

В методе `createArrayOfXValues` при создании нового массива `array = new double[steps]` исходный массив `arrayX`, переданный в метод, никоим образом не меняется. А в строке `y = array[i]` в поле `y` на каждой итерации пишется значение по умолчанию (`0.0`) из соответствующей ячейки массива.

Если нужно просто сохранить все значения `y`, полученные в методе `Tabul`, то сделать это можно так:

```
private static final double
        A = 1.5,
        MIN_X = 0.8,
        MAX_X = 2.0,
        DELTA_X = 0.005;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Double> list = tabul();
    System.out.println(list);
}

public static List<Double> tabul()
{
    List<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (double x = MIN_X; x <= MAX_X; x += DELTA_X)
    {
        double y;
        if (x < 1.7)
        {
            y = Math.PI * x * x - 7 / x * x;
        }
        else if (x == 1.7)
        {
            y = A * x * x * x + 7 * Math.sqrt(x) + Math.log10(x + 7 * Math.sqrt(x));
        }
        else
        {
            y = Math.log10(x + 7 * Math.sqrt(x));
        }
        values.add(y);
    }
    return values;
}
```

Вместо `double[]` используется `List<Double>`, но при желании можно создать массив на базе списка:

```
double[] array = new double[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    array[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Либо с использованием Java 8:

```
double[] array = list.stream().mapToDouble(e -> e).toArray();
```

В коде остались "магические константы" `1.7`и `7`. Так как я не знаю что они обозначают, то в константы их не вынес.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде бы стала ясна суть, поняла в чем была ошибка